# RegEx for decimal number with maximum length ignoring dot

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am after a regex that allows a number to be a maximum length with decimal places.

It should allow 16 numbers maximum and 3 decimal places, however the 16 max should include the decimals but not the . character. I've tried and have this so far: `^(?=^[\d\.].{0,16}$)[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,3})?$`, which is close except it allows 17 single numbers, when it should only accept 16. If I change `{0,16}` to `{0,15}` it then breaks the decimals.

Accepted values:

- 123
- 123.3
- 123.45
- 123.456
- 1111111111111.345 (totally 16 numbers)
- 11111111111111.45  (totally 16 numbers)

Rejected:

- 123.1234
- 11111111111111111 (17 characters)
- 1111111111111111.
- 111111111111111.56 (15 characters and 2 numbers = 17)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Your regex is fairly close, you may use this regex:

```
^(?=(?:\d\.?){0,16}$)\d+(?:\.\d{1,3})?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xdiqb6/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?=(?:\d\.?){0,16}$)`: is positive lookahead to assert that we have 0 to 16 digits in input where dot is optional.
- `\d+(?:\.\d{1,3})?`: Match an integer or a decimal number with 1 to 3 digits.

Comment: Oh, `(?:\d\.?){0,16}`, that's smart! I was struggling to handle the "optional dot" in the count, your approach is better :)